# Restoration in MySQL 8 is slower than MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Recently I have installed mysql 8.0.12 version and started observing that its taking too long to restore database. So I verified the same with using a backup file which I restored to MySQL 8.0.12 as well as MySQL 5.6.38.

I didn't add any variables to configuration files except datadir, socket, pid files and in MySQL 8 I added  `skip-log-bin` to stop bin logs.

Please see the timings which I got. The first one is mysql 8 and the second results is from 5.6.

```
$ time mysql < backup_file.sql
  real  5m7.485s
  user  0m1.059s
  sys   0m0.255s

$ time mysql2 < backup_file.sql
 real   1m54.475s
 user   0m1.188s
 sys    0m0.136s
```

Any insight what can be the reason behind this and how I can overcome.

Comment: All InnoDB?  Same setting for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Same size RAM?

Comment: @Rick James Both instances are in same server of 8GB RAM and all are innodb tables.  I didn't put any innodb variables to both configuration file so everything is set to default values.

Comment: Do your backup is in latin character set ?